# Performance issue: large background images in Firefox

Tags: css, html, image, firefox, canvas

I'm developing a website in which there must be at least five `<section>`s, each the size of the viewport.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBswq/).

But instead of solid colors, I'm dealing with large (at least 1000px) images, all resized according to `background-size: cover`. That works fine in WebKit browsers, but Firefox is a different story. The larger the images get, the choppier Firefox becomes. And it all has to do with `background-size: cover`. Without it, everything is smooth. In fact, I've found it applies to all image scaling in Firefox.

A coworker suggested I use `<canvas>` to draw the image offscreen to the proper size, convert the canvas to base 64, and apply it as the `background-image` to each `<section>`, but that only works for small images. Like I said, these images could be very large, so that option doesn't seem feasible.

> So my question is: how can I use these large background images, resize them properly, and maintain good performance in Firefox?

*Side note: I'm running a MacBook Pro with Retina display, so I don't think my system specifications are the issue here. It has also been tested on other non-Retina MacBook Pros and the problem persists.*

Comment: Any chance you can provide maybe one image for other Firefox users to test out?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the performance using an absolutely positioned `img` tag, styled with CSS to cover the whole section and with a negative `z-index` to work as a background? Here is an example in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SBt5W/1/)
.